Where's my missing cokernel? (Cech complex computations in algebraic geometry)
Let $X=\Bbb P^2_k$, let $Y=V(f)$ for $f$ a homogeneous polynomial of degree $2$, let $g$ be a linear form, and let $L=V(g)$. Then the ideal sheaf of $L\cap C$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_X(-1)|_Y\cong\mathcal{O}_Y(-1)$, and via the long exact sequence in cohomology associated to $$0\to\mathcal{O}_X(-2-1)\to\mathcal{O}_X(-1)\to\mathcal{O}_Y(-1)\to 0,$$ we must have $h^0(C,\mathcal{O}_Y(-1))=0$ and $h^1(C,\mathcal{O}_Y(-1))=1$ as $h^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(-1))=h^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X(-3))=0$ and $h^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X(-1))=h^2(X,\mathcal{O}_X(-1)$ while $h^2(X,\mathcal{O}_X(-3))=1$. All of this is completely general and does not depend on $f$ or $g$ as long as they have the specified degrees.
But when I try and compute an example via Cech cohomology, I run in to trouble. Let $f=z^2$ and $g=z$; the Cech complex for $\mathcal{I}_{L\cap C \subset C}$ along the covering $\{D(x),D(y)\}$ should then be $$0\to \frac{z}{x}\cdot k\left[\frac{y}{x},\frac{z}{x}\right]/\left(\frac{z^2}{x^2}\right) \times \frac{z}{y}\cdot k\left[\frac{x}{y},\frac{z}{y}\right]/\left(\frac{z^2}{y^2}\right) \to \frac{z}{x}\cdot k\left[\frac{y}{x},\frac{x}{y},\frac{z}{x}\right]/\left(\frac{z^2}{x^2}\right)\to 0$$
where the maps are the obvious ones. But the map sending $(\frac{z}{x}p(\frac{y}{x}),\frac{z}{y}q(\frac{x}{y}))$ to $\frac{z}{x}p(\frac{y}{x})-\frac{z}{y}q(\frac{x}{y})$ seems to surject on to the RHS, contradicting the calculation from the exact sequence.
If I pick $f=z^2-xy$ and $g=x-y$, I can find a 1-dimensional cokernel (happy to provide this work upon request), and I've been going a little nuts about this for a day or two now.

Motivation: I'm trying to do a simple example to see how the map $\operatorname{Pic} X'\to \operatorname{Pic} X$ splits when $X'$ is a nilpotent thickening of a plane curve. This splitting is automatic for silly reasons in characteristic zero, but it's not clear to me if this is also true in positive characteristic without taking a harder look at it.

Your mistakes: (1) Being sloppy with restriction of sheaves (2) Incorrectly writing: "The ideal sheaf of $ L \cap C \subset C $ is $ \mathcal{O}_C(-1) $ and this does not depend on what $ f $ and $ g $ are (it most certainly depends on what $ f $ and $ g $ are..)
There is also: (0) you use letters $ Y $ and $ C $ both but I'll just use $ C $ ahead.
Elaboration for (1): Recall that for a morphism $ i : \operatorname{Spec B} \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}A $ and a quasicoherent $ \mathcal{F} = \tilde{M} $ on $ \operatorname{Spec} A $, the pullback $ i^* \mathcal{F} $ is $ M \otimes_A B $. In particular, if $ B $ is $ A/I^2 $ for some ideal $ I $ of $ A $ and $ i $ is the associated closed embedding, we have that $ i^* \tilde{I} $ is $ I/I^3 $ and this is exactly the local picture when $ f = z^2 $ and $ g = z $.
In particular your Cech complex should read $$ 0 \rightarrow \frac{z/x \cdot k[y/x, z/x]}{ (z/x)^3 } \times \frac{z/y \cdot k[x/y, z/y]}{ (z/y)^3 } \rightarrow \frac{z/x \cdot k[x/y, y/x, z/x]}{ (z/x)^3 } \rightarrow 0 $$
The image of the middle arrow contains polynomials of the form $$ (z/x)\cdot [p_0(y/x) + p_1(y/x) \cdot (z/x)] - (z/y)\cdot [q_0(x/y) + q_1(x/y) \cdot (z/y)]$$
Rewrite the second term as $$ (z/x) \cdot [(x/y)q_0(x/y) + (x/y)^2 q_1(x/y) \cdot (z/x) ] $$
and subtract to get $$ (z/x)\cdot [p_0(y/x) - (x/y)q_0(x/y)] + (z/x)^2 \cdot [p_1(y/x) - (x/y)^2 q_1(x/y)] $$
For convenience write $ t = x/y $ so that the above expression is $$ (z/x)\cdot [p_0(t^{-1}) - tq_0(t)] + (z/x)^2 \cdot [p_1(t^{-1}) - t^2 q_1(t)] $$
The first bracket $ p_0(t^{-1}) - tq_0(t) $ could be any polynomial $ r_0(t,t^{-1}) $ but the second bracket $ p_1(t^{-1}) - t^2 q_1(t) $ completely misses any terms with $ t $ as the only monomials present are $ \{\cdots, t^{-1}, 1, t^2, \cdots \} $.
Therefore the cokernel is a one dimensional vector space given by $ (z/x)^2t = (z/x)\cdot(z/y) $. There's your one-dimensional cokernel.
Elaboration on (2): The closed subscheme $ L $ of $ X $ gives an exact sequence of sheaves on $ X $ as $$ 0 \to \mathcal{O}_X(-1) \to \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_L \to 0 $$
Restrict to $ C $ i.e. tensor with $ O_C $ to get an exact sequence $$ Tor^1(\mathcal{O}_X, \mathcal{O_C}) = 0 \to Tor^1(\mathcal{O}_L, \mathcal{O_C}) \to O_C(-1) \to O_C \to O_{C \cap L} \to 0 $$
where we used that $ \mathcal{O}_X $ is flat. Now the sheaf $ Tor^1(\mathcal{O}_L, \mathcal{O_C}) $ is supported on $ C \cap L $ and it is a subsheaf of a locally free sheaf $ \mathcal{O}_C(-1) $. Whenever $ C \cap L \subset C $ is zero dimensional (this is the case when the intersection is two reduced points or one fat point of order 2), this means that $ Tor^1(\mathcal{O}_L, \mathcal{O_C}) $ is torsion and hence is $ 0 $ as a locally free sub sheaf cannot contain nontrivial torsion sheaves. However if $ C \cap L $ is one dimensional (this is the case when $ f = z^2 $ and $ g = z $) this sheaf need not vanish at all, and it does not. In this case, locally that exact sequence reads as $$ 0 \to I^2/I^3 \to I/I^3 \to A/I^2 \to A/I \to 0 $$
and that is the source of all your confusions.
